# how to createNativeQuery using jpaTemplate

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

How to use createNativeQuery using jpatemplate, because jpatemplate.getEntityManager() is returning null:

```
public class GenericDAO<T, PK extends Serializable> {
    @Autowired
    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.jpaTemplate = new JpaTemplate(emf);    
    }
}
```

or can we use both entitymanager and jpaTemplate? like:

```
public class GenericDAO<T, PK extends Serializable> {
    @Autowired
    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.jpaTemplate = new JpaTemplate(emf);    
}
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void save(obj){
        this.jpaTemplate.presist(Object obj)
    }

    public List<?> createNativeQuery(String query){
        entityManager.createNativeQuery(query) ;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the entity manager, you're supposed to use the [execute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTemplate.html#execute%28org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaCallback%29) method of JpaTemplate, and put your code in the callback. JpaTemplate gives you the EM. You don't get it from the JpaTemplate:

```
return jpaTemplate.execute(new JpaCalback<List<?>>() {
    @Override
    public List<?> doInJpa(EntityManager em) {
        // your code here.
    }
});
```

Note that this class is deprecated.

Comment: Is there any new alternative api for jpaTemplate

Comment: Use the native JPA API (EntityManager methods) directly.